# I need help splitting addresses (number, addition, etc)

Tags: sql-server, string

Apologies for the fuzzy title...

My problem is this; I have a SQL Server table persons with about 100.000 records. Every person has an address, something like "Nieuwe Prinsengracht 12 - III". The customer now wants to separate the street from the number and addition (so each address becomes two or three fields). The problem is that we can not be sure of the format the current address is in, it could also simply be something like "Velperweg 30".

The only thing we do know about it is that it's a piece of text, followed by a number, possibly followed by some more text (which can contain a number).

A possible solution would be to do this with regexes, but I would much (much, much) rather do this using a query. Is there any way to use regexes in a query? Or do you have any other suggestions how to solve such a problem?

Comment: This is not a trivial issue by any way - there will likely be some addresses (in some kind of odd format) that don't fit your structure.  Do you have any idea how clean your data is?

Comment: This should [help](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql).
Cheers!

Comment: YIKES! Instantiating an external COM object - my skin crawls ....

Comment: Got any better ideas? SQL Server's rather limited in this matter

Comment: I would push back to the customer on this, this is a lot of work for absolutely no benefit. Ask them why they want to do this, what benefit are they expecting except a whole lot of money spent?

Comment: yes - SQL-CLR ! As of 2005, that's definitely the best and easiest way to extend SQL Server - beats external COM stuff hands-on, every time

Comment: @HLGEM: I disagree - the address should've been modeled as separate fields in the first place.  Realistically, people have multiple addresses - work, home at a minimum.

Comment: @Paddy, yeah, I do know how clean it is. It's about the dirtiest there is. @HLGEM, I tried to talk them out of it, but they're one of the most stubborn customers out there... 
@Ponies, you're right, it should have been clean in the first place. We imported all of this data from the clients old system which was not very tidy, to say the least...

Comment: Thanks Hal for your answer. I will take a closer look at it tomorrow, but I think this is way to complicated. For me it would probably be faster to create some external script..

Comment: @Lex, then good luck, this could take you a while...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - those would be different records not different fields. I have never seen any case where street number needs to be separate from the street name and many addresses where that is not practical or possible, not every address is modeled by street number street name. How would you store a PO box address for instance or an APO address. We even have addresses like 5770 S 250 E which is the street and whic is the number (Utah can have some very strange addresses that seem more like geographical locations than real streets)

@lex, I feel your pain. Some clients are just unreasonable.

Comment: @HLGEM: I've modeled address tables, having upwards of three lines - ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, and _3 to store things like "c/o Mr. HLGEM", PO Box addresses, etc.  Street, city, prov/state, postal code were all separate fields.  I've seen systems that isolate the suite number - my cell phone co does.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I agree I have done street1, street2 etc as well and certainly city state, country postal code should be spearated out, but what he wants is to specifically separate the number from the street which is not a good idea as that does not model well for all addresses.

Comment: @HLGEM: This reminds me of the pain of storing phone numbers.. I don't see the problem with separating house/building number from the street from a column perspective - but it'd be a royal pain to fix data like Lex has to.  I guess you mean if you want to search for an address that includes the building number?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT
   substring([address_field], 1, patindex('%[1-9]%', [address_field])-1) as [STREET],
   substring([address_field], patindex('%[1-9]%', [address_field]), len([address_field])) as [NUMBER_ADDITON]
FROM
   [table]
```

It relies on the assumption that the [street] field will not contain any numbers, and the [number_addition] field will begin with a number.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising, I will try it tomorrow!

Comment: This works pretty well!! I think I will be able to manage with this. Please note that you have syntax errors in the query, both substrings have one ')' too much at the end.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server and T-SQL are rather limited in their processing prowess - if you're really serious about heavy-lifting and regexes etc., you're best bet is probably creating an assembly in C# or VB.NET that does all that tricky Regex business, and then deploying that into SQL-CLR and use the functions in T-SQL.

"Pure" T-SQL cannot really handle much string manipulation beyond SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX - but that's about it.

Comment: +1: But you forgot about [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx), which [has limited pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: ok, I give you "very limited" pattern matching :-)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the best option indeed... Thanks, I think I will try to do something like this.

Comment: @Lex: Separate from how you implement your solution, you might be able to find more information on address-parsing rules.  You will find out that many have had this problem, and maybe they're sharing their knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your "Is there any way to use regexes in a query?", then yes there is, but it needs a little .NET knowledge. Create a CLR assembly with a user-defined function that does your regex work. Visual Studio 2008 has a template project for this. Deploy it to your SQL server and call it from your query.

Comment: +1: Why was this marked down?  It's correct - on SQL Server 2005+, SQLCLR is a means of getting regex functionality that TSQL will never natively support.

Answer (score 1):

Name and Address parsing and standardization is probably one of the most difficult problems we can encounter as programmers for precisely the reasons you've mentioned.

I assume that whoever you work for their main business is not address parsing. My advice is to buy a solution rather than build one of your own.

I am familiar with [this company](http://www.melissadata.com/).  Your address examples appear to be non US or Canadian so I don't know if their products would be useful, but they may be able to point you to another vendor.

Other than a user of their products I am not affiliated with them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the common "take a piece of complex text that could look like anything and make it look like what we now want it to look like" problem. These tend to be very hard to do using only T-SQL (which does not have native regex functionality). You will probably have to work with complex code outside of the database to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

TGnat is correct.  Address standardization is complicated.

I've encountered this problem before.

If your customer doesn't want to spring for the custom software, develop a simple GUI that allows a person to take an address and split it manually.  You'd delete the address row with the old format and insert the row with the new address format.

It wouldn't take long for typists familiar with your addresses to manually make 100,000 changes.  Of course, it's up to the customer if he wants to spend the money on custom software or typists.

But you shouldn't be stuck with the data cleaning bill, either.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but for future reference, I still decided to add an answer using regex (also so I don't forget it myself). Today, I ran into a similar problem in Excel, in which I had to split the address in street and house number too. In the end, I've copied the column to SublimeText (a shareware text editor), and used a regex to do the job (CTRL-H, enable regex):

```
FIND: ^('?\d?\d?\d?['-\.a-zA-Z ]*)(\d*).*$
REPLACE FOR THE HOUSE NUMBER: $2
REPLACE FOR THE STREET NAME:  $1
```

Some notes:

- Some addresses started with a quote, e.g. 't Hofje, so I needed to add '?
- Some addresses contained digits at the start, e.g. 17 Septemberplein or 2e Molendwarsstraat, so I added \d?\d?\d?
- Some addresses contained a -, e.g. Willem-Alexanderlaan or a '